# Installation of Apache2 while already present

Tags: apache2, debian, debian-installer

Today I was trying to install Subversion on a Debian server (5.0.8). I ran this command in ssh:

> apt-get update && apt-get install subversion apache2 libapache2-svn

Unfortunately, I didn't notice that *apache2* package was mentioned. The thing is, Apache2 was already installed, and to make things worse, running.

So my question is: are they some configurations that might have been changed upon the reinstallation of Apache2 ? Apache2 was restarted and seems to be running fine.
But I'm far from being an expert in Apache2 and Linux, so I might miss even the most obvious change ;)

Thank you

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Debian is *unfortunately* off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

It being Debian rather than Ubuntu I'm not sure this is the right place to be asking...However:

In general Debian (and Ubuntu) policy is to never silently clobber any system configuration changes made by the user.  If that happens then I'd say it's a bug, it shouldn't happen normally.

Also if any configuration files are changed then generally the package scripts will make backups of the versions before change, so you can look in /etc for these and replace them.

Edit:

Actually having thought about it, the command you ran probably didn't actually reinstall apache (unless an updated version was available, in which case it would have updated it as if you'd run `apt-get upgrade`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```